# Compare Date/Time logical, should the Date/Time must be formatted by as.POSIXct()?

Tags: r, datetime, comparison

I have a dataframe with `dim(my_data)` got `[1] 2075259 9`

I use `paste()` to combine `$Date` and `$Time`, after running
`my_data$DateTime <- strptime(my_data$DateTime, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`
and the head looks like

```
head(my_data[, c(1,2,10)], 3)

      Date     Time            DateTime
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00 2006-12-16 17:24:00  
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00 2006-12-16 17:25:00 
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00 2006-12-16 17:26:00
```

when I run some comparison code like
`my_data$DateTime[1:3] > "2007-02-02 23:59:59"`
I get `FALSE FALSE FALSE`

But after I run `library(dplyr)` and trying to use
`my_data1 <- filter(my_data, my_data$DateTime <= "2007-02-02 23:59:59")`

the warning is
`Error: Date/times must be stored as POSIXct, not POSIXlt.
Problem variables: 'DateTime'`

It seems I must use `my_data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(my_data$DateTime)`
and then use `filter()` to get the data wanted.
Confused with this because I definitely can get `TRUE` or `FALSE` by `my_data$DateTime[1:3] > "Times Here"` without using `as.POSIXct()`.

Comment: It seems you have run into a `POSIXct` vs `POSIXlt` issue by looking at the error. `strptime` gives a `POSIXlt` not a `POSIXct` object.

Comment: Replace `strptime` line with `as.POSIXct(my_data$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`